# How to build local ETH2.0 test net?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, proof-of-stake

I'd like to build ETH2.0 blockchain on my computer.
And I want to know how to become a validator using that.
I read many documents but I can't get this way.
(I think that Geth is for ETH1.0. Is this right?)
Please let me know what do I have to?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an Ethereum 2.0 client: https://github.com/sigp/lighthouse

In general, if you want to "build a blockchain on your own computer", you can run several clients on different ports and configure the client code so that your clients/nodes only have each other as peers. How you do that configuration depends on how the client is implemented; it may not even be configurable and might require changing some of the client source code yourself.